# Example for $A\otimes \prod \mathbb{Z}\neq \prod (A\otimes \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

It is well-known that in general $A\otimes \prod G_i \neq \prod (A\otimes G_i)$. I am really not sure about the case where all $G_i$ are equal to $\mathbb{Z}$. Of course we allways have the canonical map $\Psi:a\otimes (g_i)\mapsto (a\otimes g_i)$. The main question would be whether this map is surjective.

I have the feeling, that $(\frac{1}{p^n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \prod(\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z})$ is not hit by that map. But I'm not sure and even if the map above is not an isomorphism this of course is no proof that there is no isomorphism.
Are there better counterexamples, or a proof, that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod\mathbb{Z}\neq \prod(\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z})$?

Edit: Of course all tensor-products are over $\mathbb{Z}$ and of course one can generalize this question to $\otimes_R\prod R$.

Comment: As you said, and as Lord Shark explained, the canonical map $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\prod(\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z})$ is not an isomorphism. However, there exist an isomorphism between these two groups, since they are both endowed with a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure of the same (uncountable) dimension.

Comment: Is there an example where the two groups are not isomorphic?

Comment: Here is an example : $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod_n\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. I claim that this group is non zero. This is because the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\prod_n\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is injective and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat. However $\prod_n(\mathbb{Q}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is obviously the trivial group. Thus, the two groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, this one is well known. But how about $A\otimes \prod \mathbb{Z}\neq \prod(A\otimes\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @Roland could you explain the existence of an isomorphism between these two groups a little more? I don´t get your point.

Comment: @matemagreek This is just a matter of cardinality and structure. Two $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the same uncountable cardinality $\kappa$ are isomorphic, since by the axiom of choice, there exist a basis in each of them and their cardinality is necessarily $\kappa$.

Comment: I haven´t worked too much with infinite dimensional vector spaces, could you recommended to me a good book for this topic?

Comment: @Roland  What are the dimension of the two factors over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @matemagreek $2^{\aleph_0}$ : a countable product of countable sets has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. A $\mathbb{Q}$-basis needs to have the same cardinality.

Comment: @Roland Why a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis needs to have the same cardinality?

Comment: @matemagreek Because $E\simeq \mathbb{Q}^{(\mathfrak{B})}$. So the cardinality of $E$ is the same as $\operatorname{Card}(\mathfrak{B})$ (at least if $\mathfrak{B}$ is infinite).

Comment: @Roland so.. in this case the cardinality of the base should be $\aleph_{0}$?

Comment: @matemagreek No since $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod\mathbb{Z}$ is of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ as I said two comments above.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your time and patience, now it is clear. :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "$=$"?

There is a canonical map from $A\otimes\prod\Bbb Z$ to
$\prod (A\otimes\Bbb Z)$. Are you asking if this map is always bijective?

It isn't for $A=\Bbb Q$ and when the product is infinite. Any
element in the image of the map is an element of
$\prod(\Bbb Q\otimes\Bbb Z)=\prod\Bbb Q$ where the components have
bounded denominator.

Comment: This was one of my questions.
I would also be interested in an example where the two groups are not isomorphic.